# A Model field for integers with dashes in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I need a field for special identificator, to be more specific - CAS number, so the field should pass only integers and dashes. Is there a better way to hold such "dash-separated integers" than to use a CharField? Thanx.

Comment: You can write your own: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/ However, the underlying type would still have to be a charfield at the database level, so you might want to (re)consider charfield implementation to save you the extra work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to use [`RegexValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#regexvalidator):

```
cas = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$')])
```

Comment: Thanx, suppose its the easiest way. Though, i think its more natural to have an integerfield here than a charfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own django field, that will translate CAS number from one format to another. CAS is only at most 10 digits long, where last digit is checksum, so you can skip it when saving into database and calculate it on retrieving.

So even with 10 digits it will fit into integer field. Only work to do here is write django field that will translate format from one to another.